# Convert rows into columns Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle11g, pivot

This has been asked several times and has been answered as many times, but this is different because:

1. this is in Oracle 11g - other examples I have seen are in SQL Server with StUFF function
2. This requires joining 2 tables to get the info

Let me explain

This is the table that holds field names & File_ID

```sql
CREATE TABLE RESPONSE_METADATA
(
  FILE_ID        NUMBER(10)                     NOT NULL,
  FIELD_NUMBER   NUMBER(4)                      NOT NULL,
  FIELD_NAME     VARCHAR2(50 BYTE)              NOT NULL,
  FIELD_TYPE     VARCHAR2(50 BYTE)              NOT NULL
);
```

This is a table that holds the records of each file but records are separated.

```sql
CREATE TABLE RESPONSE_DETAILS
(
  FILE_ID        NUMBER(10),
  REC_FLD_1      VARCHAR2(300 BYTE),
  REC_FLD_2      VARCHAR2(300 BYTE),
  REC_FLD_3      VARCHAR2(300 BYTE),
  REC_FLD_4      VARCHAR2(300 BYTE),
  REC_FLD_5      VARCHAR2(300 BYTE),
  REC_FLD_6      VARCHAR2(300 BYTE),
  REC_FLD_7      VARCHAR2(300 BYTE),
  REC_FLD_8      VARCHAR2(300 BYTE),
  REC_FLD_9      VARCHAR2(300 BYTE),
  REC_FLD_10     VARCHAR2(300 BYTE),
  REC_FLD_11     VARCHAR2(300 BYTE),
  REC_FLD_12     VARCHAR2(300 BYTE),
  REC_FLD_13     VARCHAR2(300 BYTE),
  REC_FLD_14     VARCHAR2(300 BYTE),
  REC_FLD_15     VARCHAR2(300 BYTE),
  REC_FLD_16     VARCHAR2(300 BYTE),
  REC_FLD_17     VARCHAR2(300 BYTE),
  REC_FLD_18     VARCHAR2(300 BYTE),
  REC_FLD_19     VARCHAR2(300 BYTE),
  REC_FLD_20     VARCHAR2(300 BYTE)
);
```

Insert Data

```sql
INSERT INTO RESPONSE_METADATA (FILE_ID, FIELD_NUMBER, FIELD_NAME, FIELD_TYPE) VALUES (1,1,'REC_ID','NUMBER');
INSERT INTO RESPONSE_METADATA (FILE_ID, FIELD_NUMBER, FIELD_NAME, FIELD_TYPE) VALUES (1,2,'EMAIL','VARCHAR2');
INSERT INTO RESPONSE_METADATA (FILE_ID, FIELD_NUMBER, FIELD_NAME, FIELD_TYPE) VALUES (1,3,'CAMP','VARCHAR2');
INSERT INTO RESPONSE_METADATA (FILE_ID, FIELD_NUMBER, FIELD_NAME, FIELD_TYPE) VALUES (1,4,'ACTION','VARCHAR2');
INSERT INTO RESPONSE_METADATA (FILE_ID, FIELD_NUMBER, FIELD_NAME, FIELD_TYPE) VALUES (1,5,'DESC','VARCHAR2');
INSERT INTO RESPONSE_METADATA (FILE_ID, FIELD_NUMBER, FIELD_NAME, FIELD_TYPE) VALUES (1,6,'TIME','VARCHAR2');
INSERT INTO RESPONSE_METADATA (FILE_ID, FIELD_NUMBER, FIELD_NAME, FIELD_TYPE) VALUES (1,7,'CHANNEL','NUMBER');
INSERT INTO RESPONSE_METADATA (FILE_ID, FIELD_NUMBER, FIELD_NAME, FIELD_TYPE) VALUES (1,8,'STATUS','VARCHAR2');
INSERT INTO RESPONSE_METADATA (FILE_ID, FIELD_NUMBER, FIELD_NAME, FIELD_TYPE) VALUES (1,9,'DI_CODE','VARCHAR2');
INSERT INTO RESPONSE_METADATA (FILE_ID, FIELD_NUMBER, FIELD_NAME, FIELD_TYPE) VALUES (1,10,'CUSTOM','VARCHAR2');
INSERT INTO RESPONSE_METADATA (FILE_ID, FIELD_NUMBER, FIELD_NAME, FIELD_TYPE) VALUES (2,1,'REC_ID','NUMBER');
INSERT INTO RESPONSE_METADATA (FILE_ID, FIELD_NUMBER, FIELD_NAME, FIELD_TYPE) VALUES (2,2,'EMAIL','VARCHAR2');
INSERT INTO RESPONSE_METADATA (FILE_ID, FIELD_NUMBER, FIELD_NAME, FIELD_TYPE) VALUES (2,3,'CAMP','VARCHAR2');
INSERT INTO RESPONSE_METADATA (FILE_ID, FIELD_NUMBER, FIELD_NAME, FIELD_TYPE) VALUES (2,4,'ACTION','VARCHAR2');
INSERT INTO RESPONSE_METADATA (FILE_ID, FIELD_NUMBER, FIELD_NAME, FIELD_TYPE) VALUES (2,5,'DESC','VARCHAR2');
INSERT INTO RESPONSE_METADATA (FILE_ID, FIELD_NUMBER, FIELD_NAME, FIELD_TYPE) VALUES (3,1,'REC_ID','NUMBER');
INSERT INTO RESPONSE_METADATA (FILE_ID, FIELD_NUMBER, FIELD_NAME, FIELD_TYPE) VALUES (3,2,'EMAIL','VARCHAR2');
INSERT INTO RESPONSE_METADATA (FILE_ID, FIELD_NUMBER, FIELD_NAME, FIELD_TYPE) VALUES (3,3,'CAMP','VARCHAR2');
INSERT INTO RESPONSE_METADATA (FILE_ID, FIELD_NUMBER, FIELD_NAME, FIELD_TYPE) VALUES (4,1,'REC_ID','NUMBER');
INSERT INTO RESPONSE_METADATA (FILE_ID, FIELD_NUMBER, FIELD_NAME, FIELD_TYPE) VALUES (4,2,'ORGN','VARCHAR2');
INSERT INTO RESPONSE_METADATA (FILE_ID, FIELD_NUMBER, FIELD_NAME, FIELD_TYPE) VALUES (4,3,'LOGOS','VARCHAR2');
INSERT INTO RESPONSE_METADATA (FILE_ID, FIELD_NUMBER, FIELD_NAME, FIELD_TYPE) VALUES (4,4,'ACTN','VARCHAR2');
INSERT INTO RESPONSE_METADATA (FILE_ID, FIELD_NUMBER, FIELD_NAME, FIELD_TYPE) VALUES (4,5,'BLANK1','VARCHAR2');
INSERT INTO RESPONSE_METADATA (FILE_ID, FIELD_NUMBER, FIELD_NAME, FIELD_TYPE) VALUES (4,6,'ALERT_ID','VARCHAR2');
INSERT INTO RESPONSE_METADATA (FILE_ID, FIELD_NUMBER, FIELD_NAME, FIELD_TYPE) VALUES (4,7,'DEVNUM','NUMBER');
INSERT INTO RESPONSE_METADATA (FILE_ID, FIELD_NUMBER, FIELD_NAME, FIELD_TYPE) VALUES (4,8,'RES_CODE','VARCHAR2');
INSERT INTO RESPONSE_METADATA (FILE_ID, FIELD_NUMBER, FIELD_NAME, FIELD_TYPE) VALUES (4,9,'STRAT_ID','VARCHAR2');
INSERT INTO RESPONSE_METADATA (FILE_ID, FIELD_NUMBER, FIELD_NAME, FIELD_TYPE) VALUES (4,10,'COMP_FLAG','VARCHAR2');
INSERT INTO RESPONSE_METADATA (FILE_ID, FIELD_NUMBER, FIELD_NAME, FIELD_TYPE) VALUES (4,11,'AUDLOG','VARCHAR2');
INSERT INTO RESPONSE_METADATA (FILE_ID, FIELD_NUMBER, FIELD_NAME, FIELD_TYPE) VALUES (4,12,'STARTTIME','VARCHAR2');
INSERT INTO RESPONSE_METADATA (FILE_ID, FIELD_NUMBER, FIELD_NAME, FIELD_TYPE) VALUES (4,13,'DURATION','VARCHAR2');

INSERT INTO RESPONSE_DETAILS (FILE_ID, REC_FLD_1, REC_FLD_2, REC_FLD_3, REC_FLD_4, REC_FLD_5, REC_FLD_6, REC_FLD_7, REC_FLD_8, REC_FLD_9, REC_FLD_10, REC_FLD_11, REC_FLD_12, REC_FLD_13, REC_FLD_14, REC_FLD_15, REC_FLD_16, REC_FLD_17, REC_FLD_18, REC_FLD_19, REC_FLD_20)VALUES (8,'67537','Line','','81433','1','15062012','DELIVERED','67537','','','','','','','','','','','','');
INSERT INTO RESPONSE_DETAILS (FILE_ID, REC_FLD_1, REC_FLD_2, REC_FLD_3, REC_FLD_4, REC_FLD_5, REC_FLD_6, REC_FLD_7, REC_FLD_8, REC_FLD_9, REC_FLD_10, REC_FLD_11, REC_FLD_12, REC_FLD_13, REC_FLD_14, REC_FLD_15, REC_FLD_16, REC_FLD_17, REC_FLD_18, REC_FLD_19, REC_FLD_20)VALUES (8,'67551','Line','','81430','1','15062012','DELIVERED','67551','','','','','','','','','','','','');
INSERT INTO RESPONSE_DETAILS (FILE_ID, REC_FLD_1, REC_FLD_2, REC_FLD_3, REC_FLD_4, REC_FLD_5, REC_FLD_6, REC_FLD_7, REC_FLD_8, REC_FLD_9, REC_FLD_10, REC_FLD_11, REC_FLD_12, REC_FLD_13, REC_FLD_14, REC_FLD_15, REC_FLD_16, REC_FLD_17, REC_FLD_18, REC_FLD_19, REC_FLD_20)VALUES (8,'67579','Line','','81403','1','15062012','DELIVERED','67579','','','','','','','','','','','','');
INSERT INTO RESPONSE_DETAILS (FILE_ID, REC_FLD_1, REC_FLD_2, REC_FLD_3, REC_FLD_4, REC_FLD_5, REC_FLD_6, REC_FLD_7, REC_FLD_8, REC_FLD_9, REC_FLD_10, REC_FLD_11, REC_FLD_12, REC_FLD_13, REC_FLD_14, REC_FLD_15, REC_FLD_16, REC_FLD_17, REC_FLD_18, REC_FLD_19, REC_FLD_20)VALUES (8,'67593','Line','','81452','1','15062012','DELIVERED','67593','','','','','','','','','','','','');
INSERT INTO RESPONSE_DETAILS (FILE_ID, REC_FLD_1, REC_FLD_2, REC_FLD_3, REC_FLD_4, REC_FLD_5, REC_FLD_6, REC_FLD_7, REC_FLD_8, REC_FLD_9, REC_FLD_10, REC_FLD_11, REC_FLD_12, REC_FLD_13, REC_FLD_14, REC_FLD_15, REC_FLD_16, REC_FLD_17, REC_FLD_18, REC_FLD_19, REC_FLD_20)VALUES (8,'67607','Line','','81453','1','15062012','DELIVERED','67607','','','','','','','','','','','','');
INSERT INTO RESPONSE_DETAILS (FILE_ID, REC_FLD_1, REC_FLD_2, REC_FLD_3, REC_FLD_4, REC_FLD_5, REC_FLD_6, REC_FLD_7, REC_FLD_8, REC_FLD_9, REC_FLD_10, REC_FLD_11, REC_FLD_12, REC_FLD_13, REC_FLD_14, REC_FLD_15, REC_FLD_16, REC_FLD_17, REC_FLD_18, REC_FLD_19, REC_FLD_20)VALUES (4,'28072','16','1','189325','','ins/code.com/20120621','6551','WID ','VOLN ','N',';B10100','41061.6740856481','14','','','','','','','');
INSERT INTO RESPONSE_DETAILS (FILE_ID, REC_FLD_1, REC_FLD_2, REC_FLD_3, REC_FLD_4, REC_FLD_5, REC_FLD_6, REC_FLD_7, REC_FLD_8, REC_FLD_9, REC_FLD_10, REC_FLD_11, REC_FLD_12, REC_FLD_13, REC_FLD_14, REC_FLD_15, REC_FLD_16, REC_FLD_17, REC_FLD_18, REC_FLD_19, REC_FLD_20)VALUES (4,'28072','16','1','189325002','','ins/code.com/20120622','6551','CON ','VOLN ','N',';B10100','41061.6978240741','124','','','','','','','');
INSERT INTO RESPONSE_DETAILS (FILE_ID, REC_FLD_1, REC_FLD_2, REC_FLD_3, REC_FLD_4, REC_FLD_5, REC_FLD_6, REC_FLD_7, REC_FLD_8, REC_FLD_9, REC_FLD_10, REC_FLD_11, REC_FLD_12, REC_FLD_13, REC_FLD_14, REC_FLD_15, REC_FLD_16, REC_FLD_17, REC_FLD_18, REC_FLD_19, REC_FLD_20)VALUES (4,'28075','15','30','443433001','','ins/code.com/20120623','5908','AMP ','VOLN ','N',';B10100','41061.6737268519','13','','','','','','','');
INSERT INTO RESPONSE_DETAILS (FILE_ID, REC_FLD_1, REC_FLD_2, REC_FLD_3, REC_FLD_4, REC_FLD_5, REC_FLD_6, REC_FLD_7, REC_FLD_8, REC_FLD_9, REC_FLD_10, REC_FLD_11, REC_FLD_12, REC_FLD_13, REC_FLD_14, REC_FLD_15, REC_FLD_16, REC_FLD_17, REC_FLD_18, REC_FLD_19, REC_FLD_20)VALUES (4,'28075','15','30','4443433','','ins/code.com/20120624','5908','CON ','VOLN ','N',';B10100','41061.6953240741','113','','','','','','','');
INSERT INTO RESPONSE_DETAILS (FILE_ID, REC_FLD_1, REC_FLD_2, REC_FLD_3, REC_FLD_4, REC_FLD_5, REC_FLD_6, REC_FLD_7, REC_FLD_8, REC_FLD_9, REC_FLD_10, REC_FLD_11, REC_FLD_12, REC_FLD_13, REC_FLD_14, REC_FLD_15, REC_FLD_16, REC_FLD_17, REC_FLD_18, REC_FLD_19, REC_FLD_20)VALUES (4,'28078','11','1','2576141','','ins/code.com/20120625','6681','CON ','VOLN ','N',';B10100','41061.6764236111','81','','','','','','','');
```

Now the Problem IS

I want data to be seen this way

```sql
FILE_ID REC_ID  EMAIL   CAMP    ACTION  DESC    TIME    CHANNEL STATUS  DI_CODE CUSTOM
1   67537   Line        81433   1   15062012    DELIVERED   67537       
1   67551   Line        81430   1   15062012    DELIVERED   67551       
1   67579   Line        81403   1   15062012    DELIVERED   67579       
1   67593   Line        81452   1   15062012    DELIVERED   67593       
1   67607   Line        81453   1   15062012    DELIVERED   67607       


FILE_ID REC_ID  ORGN    LOGOS   ACTN    BLANK1  ALERT_ID            DEVNUM  RES_CODE    STRAT_ID    COMP_FLAG   AUDLOG  STARTTIME   DURATION
4   28072   16  1   189325          ins/code.com/20120621   6551    WID         VOLN    N       ;B10100 1/06/2012 16:10 14
4   28072   16  1   1893250         ins/code.com/20120622   6551    CON         VOLN    N       ;B10100 1/06/2012 16:44 124
4   28075   15  30  4434330         ins/code.com/20120623   5908    AMP         VOLN    N       ;B10100 1/06/2012 16:10 13
4   28075   15  30  4443433         ins/code.com/20120624   5908    CON         VOLN    N       ;B10100 1/06/2012 16:41 113
4   28078   11  1   2576141         ins/code.com/20120625   6681    CON         VOLN    N       ;B10100 1/06/2012 16:14 81
```

The way it needs to work is every File_ID in METADATA Table has FIELD_NUMBER. These Filed_Numbers are columns in Details table

I've tried XML PIVOT in Oracle that does not work as there are multiple nodes these columns will create.

I've tried just pivot things - does not work. THIS NEEDS TO BE DYNAMIC - THE File_ID can have any number of Fields not more than 30 though.

And this needs to be a stored proc or query - as I do not have permission to be build ETL.

Comment: How are the two blocks of your desired result related? Your test-data has `file_id` `4` and `8`, your output has `1` and `4`?

Comment: So if I understand your requirements right, then you want to do some sort of column-name "localization" (`REC_FLD_1`-> `REC_ID`)? You would have to use one dynamic query per `FILE_ID`, but why not do this on client-side? Or did I get something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this to generate a script:

```
select 'select '||FILE_ID||' FILE_ID,'||
  ltrim(sys_connect_by_path('REC_FLD_'||FIELD_NUMBER||' "'||FIELD_NAME||'"',','),',')||
  ' from RESPONSE_DETAILS where FILE_ID=' ||FILE_ID||';'
  from (select t.*,count(*) over (partition by FILE_ID) cnt from RESPONSE_METADATA t)
 where cnt=FIELD_NUMBER start with FIELD_NUMBER=1 
connect by prior FILE_ID=FILE_ID and prior FIELD_NUMBER=FIELD_NUMBER-1
```

Added double quotes because some column names are reserved "DESC" for example

Comment: @PeterLang REC_FLD_1 does not have any relation to REC_ID

Comment: Nahuel Fouilleul Thanks for script - THAT IS JUST awesome - However I forgot to mention - i'm just starting on Oracle. I tried creating PL/SQL and run the select statement that is being returned, but it is not providing me the table/result set of the Select statement. I'm using Toad. Can you please assist. I'm so grateful to you - that i've got this close - thanks to you.

Comment: Thanks for adding double qoutes - for tha sake of simplicity - i made the Column names shorter - it is actually called Description_Value in my Table

Comment: Thanks @NahuelFouilleul ..it works peerfectly as I wanted. Appreciate your help.